# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on French Language breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1          7
Users destroyed                                   3          0
Users contacted                                   2          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            47        336
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0         13
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         19        206
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        152
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0        703
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                3         96
Tags merged                                       1          0
Questions reopened                                6          0
Questions protected                               1          4
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                6         76
Questions closed                                 99         21
Question flags handled⁴                          53         29
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                   0         29
Posts locked                                      1         18
Posts deleted⁵                                  132        260
Posts bumped                                      0        110
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                                3          0
Comments flagged                                  0        117
Comments deleted⁶                               479      1,130
Comment flags handled                            39         78
Answers flagged                                   7        255
Answer flags handled                            225         37
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://french.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thank you, a Happy New Year to you too. Would you say those stats are similar to other beta sites, or other language related beta sites, and generally do beta sites differ from "production" sites in that respect. And is there any one stat here that is different from the rest of the other sites? Thanks!